# How do I use className to change appearance of html in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am currently learning ReactJS from a youtube tutorial and am trying to use className's to make the page look better. The tutorial I am following only added:
`className="card">` in the opening tag of a div element and it changed the page appearance though it does not seem to be working for me. Forgive me if this is a dumb question as I am not aware whether you have to import your own css files to change the appearance and the tutorial just did not show it. I would appreciate any responses. Thank you.

Comment: className="card" is equivalent to class="card" in html.  there is a css file somewhere that change the style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn about CSS (cascading style sheets) (:
HTML elements can be given classes like this

```html
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="card">content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And if you have a stylesheet (file ending in .css included in the `<head>` of your document

```css
/* styles.css */ 
.card {
    background-color: red;
}
```

The styles described in the `.card` class section will be applied to your html element (in this case a red background)

You probably missed a step in your tutorial about including some pre-created style sheet.

[CSS Basics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/CSS_basics)

Comment: I know how to give classes but supposedly (according to the tutorial I am using) using className with jsx and choosing a specific string as the className property of the tag will change the appearance somehow. Also I am not following some HTML, CSS and JS tutorial. I am following a ReactJS tutorial and for ReactJS you would use className instead of just class as it is HTML to JS (JSX) that you are typing.

Comment: If you inspect the page you'll see that className becomes class on the final HTML element. className is just what react calls it. You're missing some stylesheet that the tutorial is expecting you to have. If you had the stylesheet adding className would have an effect.

Comment: Oh my deepest apologies. It seems the youtuber did have some different code in their index.css. He sent a link to the github repo for the code in the description but I followed the wrong link and sent in some different code. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Answer updated after [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69532175/how-do-i-use-classname-to-change-appearance-of-html-in-reactjs/69532239#comment122900898_69532239) :

The reason for that is that the css is being imported on a component above the one where he declared that code.

Example code :

```
/* App JS */
import './App.css';
import Title from './Title.jsx';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Title />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
/* App.css */
.App{
  font-size: 14px;
}
.title {
  color: #e60000;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```
/* Title.jsx */
export default function (){
    return <div className="title">Test</div>
}
```

Comment: Thank you I will check out that page. I understand how to use CSS styles and import them as well as use className instead of class in JSX, though what I am trying to ask here is that what reason is there for the youtuber's code to work without having to import any CSS files, but it will not work for me.

Comment: Thanks to nlta, I figured out that my css code was different to the one on the tutorial so I changed the code and since it was in the index.css folder that is also imported into the index.js folder no importing had to be done in any other folder. Thank you for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

The difference here is you are wanting to write JSX, and not standard HTML... it is VERY close, with some small but important differences.... here's an example of the same thing in HTML and JSX:

HTML: `<div class="App">{/* some other code*/}</div>` 
JSX:`<div className="App">{/* some other code  */}</div>`

The difference here is class/className. JSX uses camel case for an HTML element's attributes, as well as using different names for some as in this case. This is just the start of the differences but hopefully this leads you in the right direction!